# Typescript emits no decorator metadata

Tags: typescript, reflect-metadata

I have a typescript project and would like to inspect some objects. So I installed `reflect-metadata`, enabled `experimentalDeorators` and `emitDecoratorMetadata` in `tsconfig.json`. Then I have this code:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
class Bla {
    thing: string;
}
console.log(Bla, Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', Bla, 'thing'));
```

It outputs `undefined`. I'd expect to get `String` or something else. Also, the compiled Javascript looks like this:

```
var Bla = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Bla() {
    }
    return Bla;
}());
console.log(Bla, Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', Bla, 'thing'));
```

There is no code to set the metadata. Interestingly, in the moment I add a custom decorator, I see code emitted for setting metadata:

```
function deco(target, key) { }
var Bla = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Bla() {
    }
    __decorate([
        deco,
        __metadata("design:type", String)
    ], Bla.prototype, "thing", void 0);
    return Bla;
}());
console.log(Bla, Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', Bla, 'thing'));
```

But still I get `undefined`. I also tried `Bla.prototype`, no change. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: I figured out the second problem (no metadata despite using `prototype`). It is related to Aurelia, the framework, I'm using. See [this issue](https://github.com/aurelia/polyfills/issues) for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design, decorator metadata is emitted only on decorated members. This is the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2589) and the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2577) it references, the title and first line say it all:

> Emit serialized design-time type metadata for **decorators**
>
> Add support behind an experimental compiler option to emit design-type metadata for **decorated declarations** in source.

(Emphasis added )

The issue when you add the decorator is that you need to inspect the `prototype`:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
function deco(target, key) { }
class Bla {
    @deco thing: string;
}
console.log(Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', Bla.prototype, 'thing')); // outputs String
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification, do you know the reason for that? Any idea why I don't get any metadata although I added a decorator?

Comment: @Tim-Erwin not sure for the reasoning probably that is what the ES proposal mandates, missed the second part of your question added a fix

Comment: @Tim-Erwin Although adding metadata for everything might add a lot of code and a lot of overhead, probably was a consideration as well...but I speculate

Comment: Hm, as noted in my question I tried `Bla.prototype`. Copied and pasted your code, outputs `undefined`. Hm, weird...

Comment: @Tim-Erwin yes .. strange .. it does work for me.. check the JS, does your JS contain `__decorate([
    deco,
    __metadata("design:type", String)
], Bla.prototype, "thing", void 0);` ?

Comment: Ya, it does. I was able to strip down the project and now it works. So I guess the problem is somewhere else... Thanks for your quick and helpful responses!